# Install Thunderbird 32 on Ubuntu 64

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to install 32 bit version of Thunderbird on Ubuntu 64.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you already downloaded any 32 bit version of thunderbird file?

Comment: Why do you want 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as using:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird:i386
```

Since there's multiarch is possible to do this easily without complications.